# Very Simple Linux VFS Implementation

Tags: linux, kernel, vfs

I'm somewhat stuck on this, being my first attempt at any type of kernel development. My project is a bit more complex than this, but what I'm stuck on is very basic.

I want a read only file system with some directories in the root dir, and files within them. That's it, nothing further. If I could get this hard coded, it'd be a piece of cake to modify it later to make it all dynamic, as long as I can load on the fly.

Basically, my question is this:

How do I create a filesystem so that every time I mount it and call 'ls' from the command line, I get a fresh list of files from within my module (hard coded for now, in the future will be dynamically pulled).

I have quite a bit more code than this, but this is what I am confident with so far:

```
int testfs_super(struct super_block *superblock, void *data, int silent) {
static struct inode_operations inode_operations = {
    .lookup = simple_lookup,
};
struct inode *inode = new_inode(superblock);
struct dentry *root;
save_mount_options(superblock, data);
superblock -> s_op = &testfs_ops;
/*
superblock -> s_maxbytes = 10000000;
superblock -> s_blocksize = PAGE_SIZE;
superblock -> s_blocksize_bits = PAGE_SHIFT;*/
inode -> i_ino = 0;
inode_init_owner(inode, NULL, S_IFDIR | testfs_DIRECTORY_MODE);
inode -> i_op = &inode_operations;
inode -> i_fop = &simple_dir_operations;
root = d_make_root(inode);
if (!root) {
    return -ENOMEM;
}
superblock -> s_root = root;
return 0;
}

struct dentry *testfs_mount(struct file_system_type *fs_type, int flags, const char *dev_name, void *data) {
return mount_nodev(fs_type, flags, data, testfs_super);
}
```

To elaborate, what I want to wind up with is something like this:

```
? list_files(inode* dir) {
  item1 = inode and dentry with id of 1 and random name
  item2 = inode and dentry with id of 2 and random name
  item3 = inode and dentry with id of 3 and random name
}
```

As long as I can get the files listed, I can implement the read/open based on the inode pretty easily.

Comment: Did you `strace` some `ls` command to understand exactly what syscalls are involved? Did you study the source code of `ls` (in the GNU coreutils package probably)?

Comment: From what I understand it goes back to readdir.

Comment: You are wrong (`readdir(3)` is a library function, and `readdir(2)` is an *obsolete* unused syscall). Really try `strace ls`.

Comment: Can't edit my last comment for some reason, wasn't finished.

My issue was linking this all together, which I think I have just done successfully by providing my own file_operations for the directory (every time I ask a question on here I find the answer immediately, no matter how long I've been looking).

My primary question now is if there is any reason to not just implement these myself and skip over dcache completely.

Comment: The  dcache is an essential part of the Linux kernel, and you should not skip over it.

Comment: That is good to know, I usually try to stay within convention anyway. I've straced it, looks mostly like gibberish to me. The only thing I see that seems relevant is "getdents" which according to the linux manual: "This is not the function you are interested in.  Look at readdir(3) for the POSIX conforming C library interface.  This page documents the bare kernel system call interface."

I may be in over my head here but what the hell.

Comment: Indeed, you need to interface the `getdents` syscall. But I believe that as an exercise, what you are attempting to do is not simple, because intuitively a file system don't have random contents. Maybe you could make it simpler and different: have the filesystem building a read-only "random" content at mount time (and keep that unchanged till unmount)? Also consider using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: I have considered using FUSE. I was hoping this would be simple enough that I could implement it directly, thus avoiding the overhead of FUSE.

But "random contents" seems arbitrary. Network filesystems like CIFs can easily have new files present on each directory listing. This is like CIFs, but read only, to put it very simply.

This is also why I can't simply build at mount (I had considered this), contents will definitely change while the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: I took another look, and you're right. I need to be using FUSE, hands down.